# optimise postgresql update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table in postgresql that contains over 10 Milions Row, I want to update one field:

```
update annonce set confirmed = true;
```

but the query take long time to execute, How can I optimise this query?

Comment: Could add some details? What does the table "look" like-- what are the columns, are there indexes? Are you updating the entire table or is there a where clause involved?

Comment: The table has a primary key, but "confirmed" is a field of table that i added now, and i want to specify his value to true.

Comment: Also: Foreign keys? Views? Other object referencing the table? Can you afford an exclusive lock? Other people working on it concurrently? Can you afford to truncate or delete? How big is the table (in MB) do you have enough free RAM to hold it temporarily?

Answer (score 3):

```
update annonce set confirmed = true
where not confirmed
```

A partial index could help:

```
create index index_name on annonce (confirmed)
where not confirmed
```

Compared to a full index the partial index will greatly reduce the index size and make all update, delete and insert operations faster.

Comment: To reinforce what others have written, the partial index is useful if the not confirmed records are 10% or less of the table. Perhaps you want a completely different approach where unconfirmed records are held in a separate table pending confirmation? Does this match the business logic?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it often, you want to slightly modify this as follows:

```
UPDATE announce
SET confirmed = TRUE
WHERE NOT confirmed
```

Also, you should create index on `(confirmed)`.

Today, you are changing whole table every time, which creates a lot of dead rows - basically table is bloated. With proposed method, you will be only creating dead rows for new records, and even that will be indexed - very fast and efficient.

Comment: An index on a boolean field (or any other field where the `number of rows/different values`  ratio is too high) is basically useless: it generates only more data and overhead to update and manage the table with no real benefit. Unless you want to use some fancy partial index, but this again really depends on the data and particular case.

Comment: @Eggplant You are supposing the values are evenly distributed. If the `not confirmed` rows are no more than a few percent of the table then the index could be used. But it is indeed a waste of space as a partial index would be smaller and faster. See my answer.

Comment: I don't understand why adding an index, i want just to update data on the field that i added, by the way, i tested the query, it say that the "query finished", but after my verification data didn't change.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto  Of course this is what I meant by "fancy partial index". If the portion of `not confirmed` rows is high, the performance will actually drop using the index. The query planner should be smart enough to ignore the index during SELECTs, but some overhead is required for DDL. On the other case (about 10-20% of `not confirmed`), partial index can help surely.

Comment: If this table contains 10 million rows and only new rows (which are unconfirmed) are FALSE, then this index will be highly selective for `NOT confirmed` condition and is highly desirable. However, this same index is totally useless for `confirmed` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

```
update announce set confirmed = true where confirmed = false;
```

since it's a boolean. This will do 2 things for you:

1. If the number of not yet confirmed announcements is small compared to 10 million, you can put the field into an index and let postgresql use the index for faster access.
2. In older Versions of postgresql the Free Space Map had a fixed size. If you updated a large table you'd  outgrow that map no matter how big you configured it. As a result, you had to do a periodic `VACUUM FULL` or else the disk space used by the database would grow beyond your wildest imagination.

Answer (score 0):

You have got three answers far.

***They are all wrong.***

None of them considers `NULL`. And `NULL` is the *only* thing that needs to be considered here! Since, as you revealed in a comment:

> "confirmed" is a field of table that I added now

All rows have `confirmed IS NULL` by definition. A `WHERE` clause will not help at all, jut cost a little.

Even if we did *not* know that you just added the column, since it wasn't in your original question: As `NULL` has not been ruled out, the statement would have to be:

```
UPDATE announce
SET    confirmed = TRUE
WHERE  confirmed IS DISTINCT FROM TRUE
```

But that will not help you here. Neither does an *index* -  on the contrary. The whole table has to be rewritten anyway. There is **no way around it**. There are, however, a number of things you can do, to make this faster.

It *all depends* on the information about your table you did not share with us.

Comment: Just note that the comment was posted after the answers so we were supposing the `not confirmed` **rows** were just added to an already big table containing mostly `confirmed` ones.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Did you *read* my answer? I am already addressing that. All three answers were (and are still) *wrong* in the first place. They produce incorrect results `NULL` values.

Comment: Yes I did read and I know the other answers are wrong including mine. What I'm saying is that they are wrong because they were posted before the comment clarifying that the `confirmed` column was being created in an already existing table.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I reiterate: They are all wrong to begin with. Even before the comment. The `WHERE` clause `where not confirmed` leads to incorrect results as long as we don't *know* there column is defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Yes you are right. We posted without any knowledge of the table definition so the answers should have included the provision for a null value.